# Error while creating thumbnail in php for multiple image upload

Tags: php, thumbnails

I use following code to **upload, rename, compress, create thumbnail**  everything works fine, And recently i noticed **while creating thumb it creates fresh copy of thumb images for previously uploaded images also(create thumbnail for uploaded and uploading images too)**

**Problem:**

When form is submitted it crates thumb for uploading image and uploaded images(image file that are present in older).

how do i solve this problem

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $uploadedFiles = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $errors = array();
            $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
            if ($file_type == "image/gif") {
                $sExt = ".gif";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg") {
                $sExt = ".jpg";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png") {
                $sExt = ".png";
            }
            if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
                $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
            }
            if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }
            $desired_dir = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/upload/file/";

            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);
                }
                if
                (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
                } else {
                    echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key], 0);
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
            if (!empty($row[1])) {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = $row[0];';
                eval($codestr);
            } else {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = NULL;';
                eval($codestr);
            }
        }
    }
    $orig_directory = "$desired_dir";
    $thumb_directory = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/upload/thumb/";
    $dir_handle = opendir($orig_directory);
    if ($dir_handle > 1) {
        $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_type = array();
        $ext = '';
        $title = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($file_name = readdir($dir_handle)) {
            if ($file_name == '.' || $file_name == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            $file_type = \explode('.', $file_name);
            $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));
            $title1 = implode('.', $file_type);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title1);
            if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {
                $nw = 125;
                $nh = 90;
                $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
                $stype1 = explode(".", $source);
                $stype = $stype1[count($stype1) - 1];
                $dest = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/upload/thumb/{$file_name}";
                $size = getimagesize($source);
                $w = $size[0];
                $h = $size[1];
                switch ($stype) {
                    case 'gif':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                        break;
                    case 'jpg':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                        break;
                    case 'png':
                        $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                        break;
                }
                $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
                imagepng($dimg, $dest);
                compress($source, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name, 50);
            }
        }closedir($dir_handle);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO allpostdata(im1, im2, im3, im4)"
            . " VALUES (:im1, :im2, :im3, :im4)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':im1', $file1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im2', $file2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im3', $file3, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im4', $file4, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: /post/price_plan.php');
    }exit;
}

function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}

function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight) {
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight)) {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    } else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio) {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    } else {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);
    imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    return $targetImg;
}
```

**Bounty Edit**

if there is any good and faster function to do please.

all i need is to **upload, rename, compress, create thumbnail and save name to DB**

Comment: **copy of thumb images for previously uploaded images also(create thumbnail for uploaded and uploading images too)** do you mean if you upload multiple file, last image override previously created thumbnail ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the script is not only handling the submitted images, but also *re-processing* previously uploaded images, already saved in the directory, and you want to prevent this. Right?

Comment: @jagad89 yes it overrides file ever time a form is submitted.

Comment: @Utkanos yes it is **re-processing**. it should create thumb for only uploading images only. not for file that are already saved in the directory.

Comment: would you be open to using a framework like laravel and deriviates? if so I have a solution you can use, but it will mean having a different workflow.

Comment: @Tschallacka i have no knowledge about laravel and deriviates!!

Comment: @sanojlawrence I suggest you spend some time diving into that. It has a lot of tools and existing frameworks to make tasks like this easy with minimal code

Comment: You should match the submitted images ($_FILES) in your `while`. Because you are processing every image in `$thumb_directory` at the moment. I agree with @Tschallacka your code could be more readable and maintainable with some refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is need much more optimization. you are iterating the `file` folder again every time instead of looping the just uploaded files.

```
$desired_dir = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/upload/file/";
$thumb_directory = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/upload/thumb/";
$file = [];
$nw = 125;
$nh = 90;
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $uploadedFiles = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $errors = array();
            $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
            if ($file_type == "image/gif") {
                $sExt = ".gif";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg") {
                $sExt = ".jpg";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png") {
                $sExt = ".png";
            }
            if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
                $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
            }
            if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }


            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);
                }
                $file_name_with_ext = $file_name . $sExt;
                $source = = $desired_dir . $file_name_with_ext ;
                if(!move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $source)) {
                    echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    $file[] = NULL;
                }else{
                    $size = getimagesize($source);
                    $w = $size[0];
                    $h = $size[1];
                    switch ($sExt) {
                        case '.gif':
                            $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                            break;
                        case '.jpg':
                            $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                            break;
                        case '.png':
                            $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                            break;
                    }
                    $dest = $thumb_directory. $file_name_with_ext ;
                    $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
                    imagepng($dimg, $dest);
      // imagewebp($dimg, $dest);
                    compress($source, "$desired_dir"  . $file_name_with_ext , 50);
                    compress($dest, $dest , 50);
                    $file[] =   $file_name_with_ext ;
                }
            }else{
                // TODO: error handling
            } 
        }

    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO allpostdata(im1, im2, im3, im4)"
            . " VALUES (:im1, :im2, :im3, :im4)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':im1', $file[0], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im2', $file[1], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im3', $file[2], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im4', $file[3], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: https://google.com');
    }exit;
}

function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}

function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight) {
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight)) {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    } else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio) {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    } else {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);
    imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    return $targetImg;
}
?>
```

Comment: it saves only file name `it doesn't save file extension. I want to save file name with extension also.

Comment: sitll only file name is saved, i think this `$file[] = $file_name;` should be like this `$file[] = $file_name.$sExt;` so that file name and extension will be saved.

Comment: @sanojlawrence it saves data as per your expectation and process only uploaded files.  Correct?

Comment: yes it does but, buti want  file name should be save with extension! to DB. (.jpg or .png

Comment: hey a small issue after compression i have image size of 32kb (521*768) but the thumb file is 71kb (250*180) ! any solution ?

Comment: @sanojlawrence applied compression on thumbnail also.

Comment: thumb must be created form compressed image so thumb image must also be lower size..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203480/discussion-between-jagad89-and-sanoj-lawrence).

Comment: is there any way to save uploaded file to `webp`..?

Comment: I have added a call in comment *imagewebp* in answer.

Comment: No not that instead of `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $source)` i want `imagewebp()`. i want the uploading file to be `webp` and a thumb

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty bad php-programming-habits in that code (e.g. use of eval and general data-flow).
To break it down: The script first validates the uploaded files and moves them to a temp directory. Then it calculates thumbnails for all files in the temp directory.

To change that we use an array which contains the filenames of uploading images.

```
// ...
$file_type = array();
$ext = '';
$title = '';
$i = 0;

// First change:
$validFileNames = array_column($uploadedFiles, 0);

while ($file_name = readdir($dir_handle)) {
  if ($file_name == '.' || $file_name == '..' || !in_array($file_name, $validFileNames)) {
    continue;
  }

  // Nothing changed beyond this point
  $file_type = \explode('.', $file_name);
  $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));
  $title1 = implode('.', $file_type);
  $title = htmlspecialchars($title1);

  // ...
}
```

`array_column($uploadedFiles, 0)` reads the index 0 of every entry in `$uploadedFiles`, which contains the filename. So `$validFileNames` contains only filenames of uploading images.

We then check for every file in the temp-directory if its name is included in `$uploadedFiles`. If not then it was not uploading and can be ignored.

As for the request of a more general optimization:

```
<?php

$desired_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/file/';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $uploadedFiles = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $uploadedFileName) {
            $errors = array();

            $destFilename = md5(uniqid('uploads', true).time());
            $uploadedSize = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $uploadedTmpName = $uploadedFileName;
            $uploadedType = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

            $sExt = null;
            if ($uploadedType == 'image/gif') {
                $sExt = '.gif';
            } elseif ($uploadedType == 'image/jpeg' || $uploadedType == 'image/pjpeg') {
                $sExt = '.jpg';
            } elseif ($uploadedType == 'image/png' || $uploadedType == 'image/x-png') {
                $sExt = '.png';
            }

            if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
                $errors[] = 'Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!';
            }

            if ($uploadedSize > 2097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }


            if (!empty($errors)) {
                // Todo: Error handling of $errors
                continue;
            }

            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);
            }

            $destFilePath = "$desired_dir/".$destFilename.$sExt;
            if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadedTmpName, $destFilePath)) {
                echo "Couldn't upload file ".$uploadedTmpName;
            }

            $nw = 125;
            $nh = 90;
            $source = $destFilePath;
            $stype1 = explode('.', $source);
            $stype = $stype1[count($stype1) - 1];
            $dest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/thumb/'.$destFilename.$sExt;

            $size = getimagesize($source);
            $w = $size[0];
            $h = $size[1];
            switch ($stype) {
                case 'gif':
                    $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                    break;
                case 'jpg':
                    $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                    break;
            }
            $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
            imagepng($dimg, $dest);
            compress($source, "$desired_dir/".$file_name, 50);


            $uploadedFiles[] = $destFilePath;
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO allpostdata(im1, im2, im3, im4)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

        if ($stmt->execute($uploadedFiles)) {
            header('Location: /post/price_plan.php');
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: how do i solve bad php-programming-habits **(e.g. use of eval and general data-flow)** any solution

Comment: You could just do everything in the first foreach. The second foreach also as the while is unecessary.
The use of `eval()` to generate the names of `$file1` to `$file4` is also not necessary since you could just execute the prepared statement multiple times.

Comment: Can you do it, As of now it creates thumbnail for only uploading images. can you please post a solution for bad php-programming-habits **(e.g. use of eval and general data-flow)**

Comment: Edited answer contains a refactoring of your script (functions not included)

Comment: i get error showing `Undefined index: size  tmp_name  type, sExt ` also i want to get file name like `$stmt->bindParam(':im1', $file[0], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);`

Comment: any update on file name i would lie to use `bindParam` method. i tryed `$stmt->bindParam(':im1', $uploadedFiles[0], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);` but value is NULL unable to save file name to DB

Comment: can you test your code i cant upload image i get multiple error

Comment: i get these error while try your code https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kpBa.png

Comment: Edited it. All other errrors were follow-Up errors (e.g. `$uploadedFiles[0]` undefined)

Answer (score 1):

As part of your question you asked if there was "any good and faster function to do please."

https://github.com/delboy1978uk/image

Try this! (install via Composer or just require each of the classes in if you just drop the code in yourself)

```
<?php

use Del\Image;

$image = new Image('/path/to/your.jpg'); //or gif , etc

// Or...
$image = new Image();
$image->load('/path/to/my.png');
```

You'll then have all of these commands at your disposal:

```
$image->crop($width, $height, 'center'); // Crops the image, also accepts left or right as 3rd arg
$image->destroy(); // remove loaded image in the class. Frees up any memory
$image->getHeader(); // returns image/jpeg or equivalent
$image->getHeight(); // returns height in pixels
$image->getWidth(); // returns width in pixels
$image->output(); // output to browser
$image->output(true); // passing true returns raw image data string
$image->resize($width, $height); // resize to the given dimensions
$image->resizeAndCrop($width, $height); // resize to the given dimensions, cropping top/bottom or sides
$image->save(); // Save the image
$image->save('/path/to/save.jpg', $permissions, $compression); // Save as a different image
$image->scale(50); // Scale image to a percentage
```

Loop through your POSTed uploads, load them up, save the original, resize the image, and save the thumbnail. Existing images shouldn't be touched.

Comment: but am unable to find `rename` and `compress` methods. Will follow for more updates.