# Unable to add or remove image from multiple html input field

Tags: javascript, html, image

i use https://github.com/promosis/file-upload-with-preview to display preview for multiple image

```js
var upload = new FileUploadWithPreview('myUniqueUploadId', {
  maxFileCount: 4,
  text: {
    chooseFile: 'Maximum 4 Images Allowed',
    browse: 'Add More Images',
    selectedCount: 'Files Added',
  },
});
```

```css
.custom-file-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/file-upload-with-preview@4.0.2/dist/file-upload-with-preview.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/file-upload-with-preview@4.0.8/dist/file-upload-with-preview.min.js"></script>
<form action="save.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="custom-file-container" data-upload-id="myUniqueUploadId">
    <label>Upload File <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="custom-file-container__image-clear" title="Clear Image">&times;</a></label>
    <label class="custom-file-container__custom-file">
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-input" accept="image/*" multiple aria-label="Choose File">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
                    <span class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-control"></span>
                </label>
    <div class="custom-file-container__image-preview" style="overflow: auto!important"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

it works fine, but i can't add a extra image are remove image.

https://github.com/promosis/file-upload-with-preview/issues/30#issuecomment-563352824 enableing `cachedFileArray` example

**Adding**

i added 3 images to input, i get 3 images in preview without submitting form i added 1 image now i get 4 images in preview, When i submit the form i get only 1 image upload(recently added file).

**Removing**

it happens same in removing image added 4 images and removed 1 image when i upload all 4 images are uploaded, everything happen only on preview but noting happen in `<input>`

----*Is there any other better way to do(other codes or library) But i want to use my custom upload handler.*

**PHP upload handler**

```
$desired_dir = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/upload/file/";
$thumb_directory = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/upload/thumb/";
$file = [];
$nw = 125;
$nh = 90;
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $uploadedFiles = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $errors = array();
            $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
            if ($file_type == "image/gif") {
                $sExt = ".gif";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg") {
                $sExt = ".jpg";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png") {
                $sExt = ".png";
            }
            if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
                $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
            }
            if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }


            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);
                }
                $file_name_with_ext = $file_name . $sExt;
                $source = $desired_dir . $file_name_with_ext ;
                if(!move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $source)) {
                    echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    $file[] = NULL;
                }else{
                    $size = getimagesize($source);
                    $w = $size[0];
                    $h = $size[1];
                    switch ($sExt) {
                        case '.gif':
                            $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                            break;
                        case '.jpg':
                            $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                            break;
                        case '.png':
                            $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                            break;
                    }
                    $dest = $thumb_directory. $file_name_with_ext ;
                    $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
                    imagepng($dimg, $dest);
      // imagewebp($dimg, $dest);
                    compress($source, "$desired_dir"  . $file_name_with_ext , 50);
                    compress($dest, $dest , 50);
                    $file[] =   $file_name_with_ext ;
                }
            }else{
                // TODO: error handling
            } 
        }

    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO allpostdata(im1, im2, im3, im4)"
            . " VALUES (:im1, :im2, :im3, :im4)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':im1', $file[0], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im2', $file[1], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im3', $file[2], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':im4', $file[3], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: https://google.com');
    }exit;
}

function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}

function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight) {
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight)) {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    } else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio) {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    } else {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);
    imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    return $targetImg;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code that is handling the upload? Because that code is most likely the reason for your issue.

Comment: show are your PHP script

Comment: @ChrisG yes i even thought about that and tried with https://stackoverflow.com/a/24895361/3836908 and my custom upload script https://stackoverflow.com/a/59141067/3836908

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt added `php` script also tried with this code too https://stackoverflow.com/a/24895361/3836908 but nothing works

Comment: what is the output for $_FILES array? There is a chance that you only get 1 file there

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt when ever i add or remove image it happen only on preview, if i remove a image it is removed form preview only while uploading that removed file is also uploaded.

Comment: so you get all 4 images in $_FILES regardless an image is removed or not. Right?

Comment: There's a syntax error in your PHP: `$source = = $desired_dir . $file_name_with_ext ;`

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt yes your right

Comment: buddy I think file cannot be removed since you have not asked in your Js/JQuery to remove it from input

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt how can i do that to `add` or `remove`.

Comment: also about adding image, when ou add another file (second click to upload) the previous ones are overridden so you get only latest file

Comment: @ChrisG typo error corrected it (edited)

Comment: I think my answer should give you clue on this

Comment: The library you're using supports multiple images, but in order to send them to your backend, you have to manually add `upload.cachedFileArray` to a FormData object. The library isn't supposed to be used in a `<form>` (because the input only stores the last image you've added, and submitting the form only sends that last image, regardless of previously added or removed ones)

Comment: @ChrisG so how do i add `upload.cachedFileArray` ?

Comment: I've tried a few things and I don't think you can use this library with standard form submission. It collects the file objects, but that's all it does. I've tried multiple things, including manually generating a new `<input>` for each file, but couldn't get it to work. Just use a different library that supports standard form submission.

Comment: @ChrisG can you suggest few library easy to do understand.

Comment: No, sorry, that's your job

Comment: @ChrisG here is a solution, https://github.com/promosis/file-upload-with-preview/issues/30 for `upload.cachedFileArray` now how do i solve with above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully got this to work using the method described by the author, but I'm using `fetch()` instead of jQuery:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = this.getAttribute("action"); // grab endpoint from HTML
    const fd = new FormData();   // create FormData object
    upload.cachedFileArray.forEach((file, i) => {
        fd.append("files[]", file); // append each file to FormData object
    });
    this.querySelectorAll("input[name], select, textarea").forEach(el => {
        fd.append(el.getAttribute("name"), el.value);
    });
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: fd
    });
    // optional processing of server response
    const text = await response.text();
    console.log('Success:', text);
    // what happens after upload here
    location = "https://google.com"; // navigate to Google
});
```

Add this to your script. It intercepts the form submission, creates a `FormData` object based on the File array, adds the remaining form fields, then submits it to the url stated it the form's `action` attribute.
Note that you should probably remove the `name` attribute from the `<input type="file">` on the form, since we don't want to add that to the FormData.

Comment: it works what about `text Input` are those normal form submission???

Comment: @sanojlawrence Sorry, what do you mean? Which `text Input`?

Comment: `<input type="text">` i have multiple inputs are those normal form processing ?

Comment: @sanojlawrence If you have additional inputs, you need to add their `name` and `.value` to the FormData object. The form is not sent the regular way; you have to use AJAX instead for the images, so everything has to be handled by the code I posted.

Comment: can it be done in jQuery so that i can send `<input type="text">` or how can i send data in above code

Comment: @sanojlawrence I edited the code so it picks up all `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` fields. Tested and working.

Comment: everything works fine, But even after clicking i see images are uploaded and `input` are sent but the page remains same no redirect, are refresh.

Comment: @sanojlawrence Is your PHP script sending back a reply? Does it get logged in the console?

Comment: here is the console https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhyvY.png and now solved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/3836908 is that the correct solution.

Comment: I thought that's a given but you need to remove `header('Location: https://google.com');` from your PHP script since you're no longer navigating there but requesting it via AJAX. Replace it with something like `echo count($_FILES['files']['size']) . " images uploaded";`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should just have to make sure to add the multiple parameter to your input like this:

```
input type="file" class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-input" accept="*" multiple
```

Comment: If you look at OP's code, the `multiple` attribute is already in there.